# strange absolute positioning CSS Issues

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've been having this absolute positioning CSS issue.

IE 10+ works just fine but Chrome gets distorted as shown in the images below:

Any help please.

(*this distortion seems to have started with chrome 52 update*)

**IE**

[image: IE]

**Chrome**

[image: chrome]

**HTML**

```
<div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
            <h4>New Contacts</h4>
            <h2 class="font-bold">707</h2>
            <div class="speed_l">
                <h2>39</h2>
                <small>/hr</small>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
            <h4>Visitors Today</h4>
            <h2 class="font-bold">2129</h2>
            <div class="speed_r">
                <h2>387</h2>
                <small>/hr</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.widget {
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

    .widget.style1 h2 {
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    .widget h2,
    .widget h3 {
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .speed_l {
        display: inline-flex;
        padding-left: 15px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

        .speed_l small {
            position: absolute;
            top: 87px;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #def;
        }

        .speed_l h2 {
            font-size: 30px !important;
        }

    .speed_r {
        display: inline-flex;
        padding-right: 12px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

        .speed_r small {
            position: absolute;
            top: 87px;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #def;
        }

        .speed_r h2 {
            font-size: 30px !important;
        }
```

***After Applying suggested solution***

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use relative positioning instead?

Comment: @CoderDudeTwodee im still learning CSS, the absolute was the one that i got quick results with. I will readily change to a better solution. thanks

Comment: Try snapping down your browser window, change the width and height, you'll be devastated to see the results. I am providing a relative positioning solution for you if that's okay.

Comment: much appreciated. Any solution that works is fine.

Comment: Maybe add a "position: relative;" to the ".speed_r" div?

Comment: @EricL let me try that

Comment: @EricL your suggestion: `position: relative` fixes right, but not left

Comment: Oh. @CharlesOkwuagwu, add it to ".speed_l" as well? Just a guess.

Comment: Add `position: relative` to both the divs.

Comment: @EricL I, just tried that on both, it only fixes speed_r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want:

I have updated the code.

```
.speed_l {

    display: inline-flex;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

    .speed_l small {
        position: relative;
        margin:5px;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #def;
    }

    .speed_l h2 {
        font-size: 30px !important;
    }

.speed_r {
    display: inline-flex;
    padding-right: 12px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

    .speed_r small {
        position: relative;
        margin:5px;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #def;
    }
```

Comment: after applying this solution the /hr text disaapear completly

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu I have updated the answer, let me know if it works now.

Comment: it works, thanks but i see size distortions now let me

Comment: You can tinker with the margin according to your needs. You could accept the answer if it solved your problem. @CharlesOkwuagwu

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll accept this as the solution. Please i have uploaded a picture of how it looks after your fix. is there a reason why the /hr are smaller?

Comment: That might be because of the default rendering of chrome has a smaller visual output than IE. You can see every text is smaller than IE. So, you might wanna just increase the font size to a level everyone can easily see.